# want to show static value from system setting in admin grid using UI component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

want to show static value from system setting in admin grid using UI component 
This field not in collection

```
<column name="taxcode" sortOrder="42" class="Stream\Sage\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Taxcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: Paste the code you have

Comment: ok provide you the code

Comment: You should paste your data provider. Your Custom Column Code as well as the error your are getting.

Comment: not getting any error only problem is that collection doenst contain taxcode column and not calling prepareDataSource();

Comment: i want to show value from system setting in admin grid

Comment: Well inject the values in the collection you feed as data source

Comment: how to inject this field into collection?

Comment: In your data provider. In the getData() method

Comment: can you share the code